# React Router history.goBack() is not working properly?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using [Electron React Boilerplate](https://github.com/electron-react-boilerplate/electron-react-boilerplate) for creating a app. I'm facing a weird issue with react-router-dom.

My application code (simplified):

In **App.tsx**

```
      ...
         {user.isLoggedIn ? <Dashboard/> : <LoginComponent/>}
       ...
```

***LoginComponent*** contains authentication logic.

In ***Dashboard*** component, I have react-router setup, as follows:

```
...other imports...
import {
  Switch,
  Route,
  BrowserRouter as Router
} from 'react-router-dom';

  ...some code...
  <Router>
    <Switch>
          <Route path="/" exact>
            <SomeComponent />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/upload" exact>
            <UploadPage />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/info" exact>
            <InfoPage />
          </Route>

          // added for testing, explained below
          <Route path="/" >
            <TestComponent />
          </Route>
  </Router>
...some code..
```

**In UploadPage:**

```
 ...
 const history = useHistory();
 ...

 <Button onClick={() => history.push('/info')}>Go To Info</Button>}
 
 ...
```

**In InfoPage:**

```
 ...
 const history = useHistory();
 ...

 <Button onClick={() => history.goBack()}>Go Back</Button>} // Instead of going back to Upload Page, it opens a blank page
                                     
 
 ...
```

**Issue:**
In **InfoPage**, When user click on `Go Back` button, instead of going back to `UploadPage`, it redirects to a blank page. To caught any non-matching route, I added a `<Route path="/" > <TestComponent /> </Route>` as a last route in `Switch` statement of **Dashboard** component. Now, when user click on `Go Back` button, it redirects to `TestComponent`. In **TestComponet**, when I print `url` and `path` (`const {url, path} = useRouteMatch()`) in console, both are `/`.

I'm using:

```
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
```

Any help is appreciated.

---

**Update**

I added, `history.listen((a, b) => console.log(JSON.stringify(a), JSON.stringify(b)))` to check what's happening. On click of `Go to Info` button, it logs `{"pathname":"/info","search":"","hash":"","key":"ljso73"} "PUSH"` and on click of `Go Back` button, it logs `{"pathname":"/D:/upload","search":"","hash":"","key":"lyhxi5"} "POP"`, which is strange. My project is placed in `D:` directory but inside some folders (not in root of `D:` directory).

Comment: Can you tell us which version of `history` package do you have ?

Comment: Initially it was `"history": "^5.0.0"`, but I have changed it to `"history": "^4.7.2"`. But it didn't solved my issue.

Comment: I had the same problem with version `^5.0.0`. I read the issues and I have found that there is a problem with this. So I downgrade to  `4.10.1` and everything work again

Comment: @gionic I changed `history` package version to `4.10.1` but still its not working.

Comment: Even on first load,  its opening `<TestComponent/>` instead of  `<SomeComponent/>`. This is weird for me.

Comment: Please check update in question, now If I add route like this `<Route path="*/upload">...</Route>`, it works. But this is not the right way. Anyone?